# Postgresql how to trim specifically either front or back of emoji

Tags: postgresql, trim

In my database i have these emojis here

```
 Limited Stock & Specials  (Must be 21 to purchase)
 Limited Stock & Specials  (Must be 21 to purchase)
 Limited Stock & Specials  (Must be 21 to purchase)
 Limited Stock & Specials  (Must be 21 to purchase)
 Limited Stock & Specials  (Must be 21 to purchase)
 Limited Stock & Specials  (Must be 21 to purchase)
 Limited Stock & Specials  (Must be 21 to purchase)
```

I want to get rid all of the emoji and the (Must be 21 to purchase)
how can i do this with postgresql script.

the table is called **restaurant_items** and the column is called **dish_type**.

theres more data that is like this in my data base but i want to learn how to deal with this first.

I tried using trim but it since its in the middle it would trim either all of left or just the emojis on the right
thanks

Comment: `UPDATE restaurant_items SET dish_type = 'Limited Stock & Specials' WHERE dish_type = ' Limited Stock & Specials  (Must be 21 to purchase)';`, do you have any other values?

Comment: this worked thanks! i do but i will change it with this format! :)